# Property 'doc' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollectionGroup<Onsiteinterface>'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can edit data in collection but if I change to Subcollection I got error. It say "Property 'doc' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollectionGroup"

```
 update(uid: string, data: any): Promise<void>
   {return this.Reqref.doc(uid).update(data);}
```

[collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EIIy.png)
[subcollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB1Lf.png)

Comment: A `CollectionGroup` refers to all documents that are contained in a collection or subcollection with a specific collection ID

Comment: so I cant use collection group?

Comment: You can use to get data but your not allowed to set data

Comment: @shycat Can you please share your database structure where we can see your collection and subcollection? This should help to have a better idea about what you are asking.

Comment: I was put at the question @FaridShumbar

Comment: for now I copy the document id manually to edit subcollection data

Answer (score 1):

Posting Ashish's comment as community wiki answer for visibility.

A CollectionGroup refers to all documents that are contained in a collection or subcollection with a specific collection ID, So using collection group you cannot set data all at once. You have to call individual documents to set data.